# serializing and deserializing Ruby objects in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, yaml, datamapper

I'm just starting in on DataMapper and find myself doing this sort of thing a lot:

```
class MyModel
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :serialized_credentials, String

  def credentials
    @credentials ||= YAML.load(self.serialized_credentials)
  end

  def credentials=(c)
    @credentials = nil
    self.serialized_credentials = YAML.dump(c)
  end

end
```

This allows me to pass a hash (for example) for credentials.

But does DataMapper already provide a mechanism for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Object` type DataMapper provides:

```
class MyModel
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :credentials, Object
end
```

This will however use `Marshal.dump` instead of `YAML.dump`, but you could DRY this up by defining your own type:

```
class YAMLObject < DataMapper::Type
  primitive String

  def self.dump(value, property)
    Base64.encode64(YAML.dump(value))
  end

  def self.load(value, property)
    value.nil? ? nil : YAML.load(Base64.decode64(value))
  end
end
```

Then you can use it just like any other type:

```
class MyModel
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :credentials, YAMLObject
end
```

Last but not least there is the `Json` type available from the `dm-types` gem which uses MultiJson to dump and load the data.

References (Object Type):

- http://datamapper.rubyforge.org/dm-core/DataMapper/Types/Object.html
- http://datamapper.org/docs/properties.html

References (Define own Type):

- http://datamapper.rubyforge.org/dm-core/DataMapper/Type.html

References (Json Type):

- https://github.com/datamapper/dm-types

Comment: Lovely and complete answer.  I think Marsal.dump will work for my needs, i.e. I only need to declare the property as an Object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are native DataMapper types you can use too.

From http://datamapper.org/docs/dm_more/types.html:

> Serializers
>
> These store values in the data-store using text based serialization
>   formats. They work via calling dumping the object to the format on
>   saving and parsing the text to reinitialize them on loading.
>
> ```
> Csv
> Json
> Yaml
> ```

So something like

```
class MyModel
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :credentials, Json
end
```